# How do I set Deluge to open .torrent files?

Tags: files, bittorrent, deluge

In Xubuntu, I can't locate Deluge with the "Open With" option. How can I associate Deluge with .torrent files so it automatically opens them in Deluge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must do a secondary click over the file and select the `Open with another application` option.
2. then select the `Show others applications` button below this window. As you can see in the following image:

[image: screenshoot]

*Do not take as reference the text (is in spanish), but the image.*

There you will see the all the applications installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Select ***Open with > other***  then navigate to *usr/bin/* click on **deluge or deluge-gtk** then click on "*Do this automatically for files like this from now on*".

Answer (score -2):

Do u have any other torrent clients in your system. If u have; then remove it and the Deluge will become your default client.

Comment: I don't consider this as a real answer..